# Minimax algorithm with TicTacToe not working properly

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I already posted a similar question here in this forum but since the old post got a little long and I rewrote my algorithm I'm starting this new post.
The old post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480187/tic-tac-toe-and-minimax-creating-an-imperfect-ai-on-a-microcontroller).

---

So I'm simply trying to implement a minimax algorithm for my TicTacToe game, except it turned out to be quite hard and even after days of trying to find the mistake, I cannot find it. you can find my code below. First, I have a few definitions, typedefs and declarations:

```
typedef signed char s8;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef s8 score;

#define STATE_00    getBoardState(0, 0)
#define STATE_01    getBoardState(0, 1)
#define STATE_02    getBoardState(0, 2)
#define STATE_10    getBoardState(1, 0)
#define STATE_11    getBoardState(1, 1)
#define STATE_12    getBoardState(1, 2)
#define STATE_20    getBoardState(2, 0)
#define STATE_21    getBoardState(2, 1)
#define STATE_22    getBoardState(2, 2)

typedef enum {
    EPlayerX = 1,
    EPlayerO
} EPlayer;

typedef enum {
    EMinimizing = 0,
    EMaximizing
} EMinMax;

static u8 g_boardState[3][3] = {
    {0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 0, 0,},
    {0, 0, 0,},
};
```

These are followed by some functions:

```
u8 getBoardState(u8 row, u8 column);

EPlayer isWon(void)
{
    EPlayer winningBoards[8][3] = {
        {STATE_00, STATE_01, STATE_02},
        {STATE_10, STATE_11, STATE_12},
        {STATE_20, STATE_21, STATE_22},
        {STATE_00, STATE_10, STATE_20},
        {STATE_01, STATE_11, STATE_21},
        {STATE_02, STATE_12, STATE_22},
        {STATE_00, STATE_11, STATE_22},
        {STATE_20, STATE_11, STATE_02},
    };
    u8 i;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        if( (winningBoards[i][0] != 0) &&
            (winningBoards[i][0] == winningBoards[i][1]) &&
            (winningBoards[i][0] == winningBoards[i][2])){
                return winningBoards[i][0];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

u8 getBoardState(u8 row, u8 column)
{
    return g_boardState[row][column];
}

void setBoardState(u8 row, u8 column, u8 state)
{
    g_boardState[row][column] = state;
}

u8 isDraw(void)
{
    u8 i, j;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){
            if(getBoardState(i, j) == 0){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void dumpTable(score table[3][3])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%6i ", table[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

EPlayer playerSwitch(EPlayer player)
{
    if(player == EPlayerO) return EPlayerX;
    if(player == EPlayerX) return EPlayerO;
    return 0;
}

EMinMax modeSwitch(EMinMax mode)
{
    if(mode == EMaximizing) return EMinimizing;
    if(mode == EMinimizing) return EMaximizing;
    return 0;
}
```

Then there is the actual minimax algorithm here called `scoring`:

```
score scoring(EMinMax mode, EPlayer player, u8 depth)
{
    score thisScore, tempScore;
    if(mode == EMaximizing){
        thisScore = -20;
        if(isWon()) return 15-depth;
    }
    if(mode == EMinimizing){
        thisScore = 20;
        if(isWon()) return depth-15;
    }
    if(isDraw()){
        return 0;
    }

    u8 i, j;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){
            if(getBoardState(i, j) == 0){
                setBoardState(i, j, player);
                tempScore = scoring(modeSwitch(mode), playerSwitch(player), depth+1);
                if((mode == EMaximizing) && (tempScore > thisScore)){
                    thisScore = tempScore;
                }
                if((mode == EMinimizing) && (tempScore < thisScore)){
                    thisScore = tempScore;
                }
                setBoardState(i, j, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    return thisScore;
}
```

And finally a function printing the scores in a table as well as the `main`:

```
void printSocredBoards(EPlayer player)
{   
    score thisScore[3][3] = {
        {STATE_00, STATE_01, STATE_02},
        {STATE_10, STATE_11, STATE_12},
        {STATE_20, STATE_21, STATE_22},
    };
    int i, j;
    if((isWon() == 0) && (isDraw() == 0)){
        for(i=0; i<3; i++){
            for(j=0; j<3; j++){
                if(getBoardState(i, j) == 0){
                    setBoardState(i, j, player);
                    thisScore[i][j] = scoring(EMaximizing, playerSwitch(player), 0);
                    setBoardState(i, j, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dumpTable(thisScore);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    printSocredBoards(EPlayerO);

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, this algorithm should work fine, however it gives me a nonsensical output:

```
 7      7      7 
 7      0      7 
 7      7      7
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is the definition of getBoardState?

Comment: @clarasoft-it it says that a few lines below.

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: @4386427 I expected that the corners should have a higher score. But it's not just with the initial board. If I put some moves in the `g_boardState`, it's not better. Oftentimes, it does not recommend me to block for example.

Comment: Why do you call `playerSwitch` in the function `printSocredBoards` ?

Comment: I would expect something like `if(isWon() == player)` rather than `if(isWon())`  `isWon()` returns non-zero (true) if _somebody_ won.

Comment: @4386427 because with the `printScoredBoards` I set every position on the board to `EPlayerO` one after the other. Thus I have to then give my `scoring` function the opposite player since it is no longer O's turn.

Comment: @chux `player` couldn't have the same value as `isWon()` though because the player previously has been switched. It is also easier that way since `scoring` is not dependent of what player started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem lies with this chunk of code from scoring where your cases are flipped from the correct return values:

```
if(mode == EMaximizing){
    thisScore = -20;
    if(isWon()) return 15-depth;
}
if(mode == EMinimizing){
    thisScore = 20;
    if(isWon()) return depth-15;
}
```

Intuitively, the problem is that when `scoring` reaches this point in the code, the call to `isWon` is evaluating the result of the *previous* piece placement, which was made with the other choice for `mode`.

For example, when scoring is called with `EMaximizing` and the board state is already won, then that implies that the player who is `EMinimizing` wins in this state and the returned score should reflect this (i.e. it should be negative). Since depth reaches a maximum of 8 your return value when `mode == EMaximizing` is always positive, which is not what you want.

When the cases are reversed, your program outputs all zeroes, which seems more sensible as perfect players should always draw. I also tested the code with the following line added to the top of `printScoredBoards` to hard-code the first play to the top-left corner:

```
setBoardState(0, 0, playerSwitch(player));
```

This yields the following:

```
 0     10     10 
10      0     10 
10     10     10
```

Correctly identifying both that the second player cannot choose the top-left and will lose if they play anything other than the center as their opening move.

Comment: Shouldn't the score of the state you are describing be:

       X    -10    -10
    -10       0    -10
    -10    -10    -10

Comment: Also, if I input the following state: `O  0  0  0  X  0  0  0  0`, shoudn't I get a score that suggests to put the next `O` in the bottom-right corner rather one that outputs all 0s?

Comment: Or was I just misunderstanding the purpose of this algorithm? Is it actually describing the outcome of a game if a player puts this mark on a position and both play perfectly from then on?

Comment: For each possible play, you are computing the end result from optimal play (by both players). In the scenario you described above where O played first in upper left, then X played in center, there is no choice for O that subsequently leads to anything other than a draw (assuming optimal play), no?